# I want to randomly change div position in angular

Tags: angular

I want to change div posisition randomly in anguar

I was try everthing but it can not works

```
  styleUrls: ['./slot-game-home.component.css'],
  animations:[
    trigger('btncaseout',[
      state('move', style({
        transform: 'translateX(300px) ',
      })),
      transition('state=>move',animate('3000ms ease')),
    ])
  ]

})
```

```
<div type="button" #username id='caseout' (click)="onClick()" [@btncaseout]="position" (mousemove)="changePosition()">Case OUT</div>


It moves only one directions
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to drag a div dynamically, Here is the stackbliz example of dragging a div.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngconf-dragdrop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

It is based on npmjs package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngconf-dragdrop

> Disclaimer: The above mentioned package belongs to me